# The argument type 'dynamic Function(AppLovinAdListener)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'dynamic Function(AppLovinAdListener?)'

Tags: flutter, ads, applovin

I'm trying to add Applovin Interstitial ads to flutter app. But it keep showing errors. my sdk is sdk:'>=2.12.0 <3.0.0'.

This are the errors displayed

> A value of type 'bool?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'bool'.
> Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'bool'.

> The argument type 'dynamic Function(AppLovinAdListener)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'dynamic Function(AppLovinAdListener?)'.

This is the sample code:

```
  const CollectionCard();

  @override
  State<CollectionCard> createState() => _CollectionCardState();
}

class _CollectionCardState extends State<CollectionCard> {
  AppLovinListener? get listener => null;

  void initState() {
    FlutterApplovinMax.initInterstitialAd('91b26a7777e1b455');
    super.initState();
  }

  bool isInterstitialVideoAvailable = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    /*24 is for notifications bar on Android */
    final double itemHeight = (size.height - kToolbarHeight - 28) / 2;
    final double itemWidth = size.width / 4;
    return Container(
        child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 0.0, 10.0, 10.0),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          GridView.count(
            primary: true,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 20),
            crossAxisSpacing: 10, //Reduce Horizontal Spacing
            mainAxisSpacing: 10, //Reduce Vertical Spacing
            crossAxisCount: 3,
            physics: ScrollPhysics(),
            childAspectRatio: (6 / 8),
            // (itemWidth / itemHeight),
            shrinkWrap: true,
            children: <Widget>[
              Card(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                ),
                elevation: 2,
                color: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
                child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () async {
                    isInterstitialVideoAvailable =
                        await FlutterApplovinMax.isInterstitialLoaded (listener);
                        
                    if (isInterstitialVideoAvailable) {
                      FlutterApplovinMax.showInterstitialVideo(
                          (AppLovinAdListener event) => listener (event));
                    }

                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (ctx) => LearnPage(),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  child: Center(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                      children: [
                        ImageIcon(
                          AssetImage('assets/icons/learn.png'),
                          color: kLightPrimary,
                          size: 60,
                        ), // Icon(
                        //   layout.icon,
                        //   size: 40,
                        // ),
                        Text(
                          'Learn',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 14,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Below is an image of the code error

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bool is a strict boolean - it can be true or false, nothing else. 
bool? is a loose boolean or also called nullable - it can be true, false or null. 
Same goes for the function. 
The Plugin 'AppLovin' I assume you are using or the package, or the function you declared, **doesn't support null-safety**, which means that it's functions **can return null.**
 In order to solve the issue, you need to make the types **nullable** by adding a question mark after the type declaration (i.e. `bool a;` will become - `bool? a;` and make sure you **don't call a method on a null**. Since your variables and methods **can return null**, the editor will inform you before hand that this (the variable) *might be null* and calling a method on it will throw a `MethodNotFoundException`. Therefore, you should add your own logic to assure that this doesn't happen and satisfy the compiler by **adding null-checks** (exclamation marks - '!') to method calls which works as a form of asserting the compiler that this value **isn't null**, despite it being **nullable.** If it so happens that you do call a null on a value with a null check, at run time (after you press the run and load your page) you will get the following exception - `Null-check used on a null value.`

Comment: You're right @Miroslav Blagoev, how do I solve it? The button is not clicking through nor does the ads show. It displays this exception 'Null-check used on a null value'.

Comment: @MuhammadZakari, as I explained above, you have to make your variables nullable by adding '?' to the variable declaration.

Comment: Yes I did, but I'm finding it hard to fix the 'Null-check used on a null value' error. Please, check my updated question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72251945/null-check-operator-used-on-a-null-value-while-creating-interstitial-ads

Comment: @MuhammadZakari on this line: AppLovinListener? get listener => null; you are setting the listener to null. Set it to a non-null value or reassign it to a non-null. I suggest you read more about listeners and how they work!